# Is there any windows store application release configuration like app.config

Tags: configuration, windows-8, visual-studio-2012, release

i am building a windows 8 store application that will connect to some backend feed. I have all the code in place - but i need to create a package for our test environment and for the production environment. They will obviously use different URLs.

In a normal windows forms/console application i would have one version of the binaries and two app.config files which would host the URLs. As Windows 8 is created as a pacakge - is there any way to have such a config that is not included inside of the package but stored separately and installed during setup? For now the app will not go to the windows store but will be delivered manually to a few devices.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no app.config file associated with a Windows Store style app.  You could however add an XML file to your app package and access that at runtime with [conditional compilation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx) and the [ms-appx protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh967755.aspx). But, you would be without all the nice utility functions associated with an app.config.

Comment: That's close to how we do it in our app: a pre-build step will, depending on the configuration, copy a file called config_debug.js or config_release.js into the file config.js which is included in the project. Then we can just use that file and have different environments depending on the configuration.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. The pre-build step seems to be a great suggestion as well! But in all cases it seems the only option is during build time and not possible during deploy time.